# APACHE POI: How to add FORMULATEXT to POI at run-time?

Tags: java, excel, excel-formula, apache-poi

I have an `Excel File` generated using `Apache POI` and I use `FORMULATEXT` in a cell; this is the formula I insert in the cell:

```
cell.setCellFormula("IF(P"+(row+1)+"<>\"\",MID(FORMULATEXT(P"+(row+1)+"),3,LEN(FORMULATEXT(P"+(row+1)+"))),\"-\")");
```

where `row` is an `int` passed to my function.

When I try to evaluate this cell the result is the sequent Stack Trace:

```
Caused by: org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NotImplementedFunctionException: _xlfn.FORMULATEXT
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.UserDefinedFunction.evaluate(UserDefinedFunction.java:56)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.evaluate(OperationEvaluatorFactory.java:135)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:537)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:264)
    ... 18 more
```

I've understand that what I should do is to add `FORMULATEXT` to `POI` at run-time.

Can somebody help me to understand how to realize this purpose?

Comment: "When I try to evaluate this cell ": Why? Why not delegate re-calculation to Excel as described in https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/eval.html#Recalculation+of+Formulas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. It seems like you are not familiar with the standards of Stack Overflow regarding questions. Please read following article: [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option.

Please format your code using the formatting tool.